# a month out / a ways out -- use of "out"?

Tags: word-usage

[Example (audio)](http://vocaroo.com/i/s0cMvHs0dBe7):

> Let's do a search. And let's pick the one that's closest to me. We'll put a check mark next to that. And click on "next". And now I select my date. I recommend that you try to schedule your exam at least **a month out**. And the reason I say that is sometimes testing centers are very busy. It's difficult to get in tomorrow or this week or next week sometimes. Things tend to book up. So, let's go **a ways out**. Let's say I want to register for October 15. I can select a time. I'll say 9 AM. Once I select a time, I click on "select appointment". It says my appointment is selected.

What can you tell me about the use of *out* in these two examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Out* here is a spatial metaphor.

We say things like "He lives a mile **out** of town", measuring *how far* from town he lives. We extend this only a little in expressions like "We stopped sixty miles **out** of Omaha", measuring the distance we still had to go before reaching Omaha, or the distance we had travelled from Omaha before stopping; and from that use it's a very short step to "We stopped an hour **out** of Omaha", measuring the temporal 'distance'—the amount of time it would take or took to cover that distance.

In your example, there's no question of measuring the time *after* the exam—you can't very well schedule an exam that's already happened!—so the expression "a month out" means that you should schedule your exam at least a month *before* you take it.

And "let's go a ways out" means "let's select a date well after the present". (*A ways* means "at a [considerable] distance". The apparent plural *ways* is actually a colloquial linguistic fossil, left over from a time when the genitive was used to cast a noun or adjective as an adverb—compare *alway**s***, *twi**c**e*.)

Answer (score 2):

The basic meaning of out is "Away from a centre", but as with many common words there are hundreds of shades of meaning.

"A month out" means "afterwards" http://www.thefreedictionary.com/out (sense 13). Figuratively, "a month out" is on month away from the central time (the date that was checked)

"A ways out", is a transcription of spoken English (and feels like a dialect to me, not certain which one) It suggests "some long time afterwards")

The quoted text reads like a transcription of spoken English. Notice the repeated sentences starting "And"